# Extension host terminated unexpectedly Jupyter notebook VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Whenever I am trying to run my jupyter note book in  VS code. I am getting the error `Extension host terminated unexpectedly`. I only have two extensions running Microsoft's python extension and  Microsoft's jupyter notebook extension. Here are the log files and I do not have any git dependency.
[image]

Is it due to insufficient memory in RAM? I am working on 56 GB machine and I do not think it is due to insufficient RAM.